# Can't fetch data using where id matches

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am getting data from leaves table using employee_id and using those fetched data i am trying to join another table to fetch both data where leave type id matches common data. But i am only getting Leave_Type data. I need to fetch both Leaves and leave Type Data where Leave_type.id == Leaves.leave_type_id. I am new to Node. Can anyone help me out yrr....

[image: Leaves Table]

[image: Leave Types Table]

```
    router.get('/getManageLeave', async (req,res)=>{
       let data= await  models.leaves.findAll({
            where: {
                employee_id: req.query.employee_id,
            },
        })
        if(data){
            data.forEach(data=>{
                models.leaves.findAll({
                    where: {
                        id: data.leave_type_id
                    }
                }).then(data => {
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        res.json({
                            status: 200,
                            data: data
                        })
                    }
                     console.log("Data---->"+JSON.stringify(data));
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    return err;
                })
            })
    
        }else{
            res.json({
                status: 400,
                message: "Error"
            })
        }
    
    })
```

Comment: Show (in the post) what format of data you need to return from this route.

Comment: Do I get it correctly that you need to get all leaves that have the same leave type id as all the leaves have with a given employee id?